# Can I ask this kind of question?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> Question: Can I ask in this way:

1) He was happy **to** brother's marks in the diploma *(He was happy **because of** brother's marks in the diploma)*

2) He was happy **to** the weather. Means *(He was happy **because of** the weather)*

3) He was happy **to** the rain. Means *(He was happy **because** of the rain)*

Comment: No. Can you explain why you want to use *to*?

Comment: @user3169 The point of my question is to understand this specific conception

Comment: The only way you can use *"Happy to + noun"* is if you're the author of the **Happy to You** album by Miike Snow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we don't say "happy to *noun*".  We only use *happy to* with a verb, like

> He was happy to join us.
>   She is happy to see them.

For nouns, we can say *happy because of*, or *happy about* or *happy for* or *happy with*, like

> He was happy about his brother's marks.
>   He was happy for the rain.
>   We were happy with the price of the car.

Comment: Thanks. What do you say about this example _I am deeply grateful to my parents_ ?

Comment: What about **happy with**?

Comment: @SovereignSun - Good point.  I'll add that too.

Comment: @Max - **Grateful to** is OK.  We say "grateful to *noun*" but not "happy to *noun*".  That's just the way it is - which preposition to use is just something you have to learn for each individual case.

Comment: Another interesting part is **happy to + that**. *We are happy to that you no longer need to watch over your sister* or "He's happy to that our family is coming along this weekend* This was used in yearly English but isn't so common nowadays is it? I wonder if anyone still speaks like that?

Comment: @SovereignSun - I've never seen **happy to that**, even in older books, and it looks wrong to me.  Where did you find it used?

Comment: @Stangdon I've read many books, remember meeting this once or twice in Old-English.. some stories about evil beasts, like Diablo.

Comment: @SovereignSun - I found a couple occurrences of "happy to that", but all of them either look like parts of a larger phrase, like ["his life is happy to that degree"](https://books.google.com/books?id=JeT0CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA88&dq=%22happy%20to%20that%22&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q=%22happy%20to%20that%22&f=false) or just mistakes, like ["I am happy to that we are honoured"](https://books.google.com/books?id=BpoiBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA101&dq=%22happy%20to%20that%22&pg=PA101#v=onepage&q=%22happy%20to%20that%22&f=false).

Comment: @stangdon Maybe it's some emphatic way? I guess this may raise a new question.